# Why is onMenuOpened is not called?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

An app hides the action bar in the following way:

```
    uiOptions =  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
    //Hide both the status bar and navigation bar
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

When the screen is touched, the following method is called to show the action bar:

```
uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Everything works as expected except when the overflow menu is opened after the 3-dot is tapped, onMenuOpened of the activity is not called, but the menu is opened normally.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=171440).

> The reason that onMenuOpened() and onPanelClosed() are not called is
>   that Activity's default implementations of those methods will try and
>   init the framework Action Bar.

Comment: I have noticed that onPrepareOptionsMenu() is called when the 3-dot overflow menu is tapped.